# LAUNCHER open: Permission denied

Tags: android, android-intent

Testing Navigation Drawer with Material Design App. When I run the app in Android Studio, I got the following error. App is installed in my phone but could launch. Please let me know what permission I am missing to add.

```
Launching application: com.jobsclipper.jobs/com.jobsclipper.jobs.MainActivity.
```

> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n
>   "com.jobsclipper.jobs/com.jobsclipper.jobs.MainActivity" -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER open:
>   Permission denied open: Permission denied Starting: Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.jobsclipper.jobs/.MainActivity }

Here is My manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jobsclipper.jobs"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<!-- for most things, including card.io & paypal -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```